# Go | Миграции баз данных MySQL | PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, golang, devops, микросервисы

**В чем суть:**

В Laravel (да, да, опять php) есть встроенные механизмы миграции бд, и комманды. Обычно миграциями мы выкатываем новые таблички, или докатываем столбцы (если очень мало данных).

**Внимание, пример вывосаный из пальца:**
Если нужно колонку с полем text выгреcти, и сохранить в другой таблице с типом json - используем комманды.

В данный момент использую MySQL (будет и PostgreSQL). Но так как я переписываю микросервисы с php на go, у меня уже есть смигрировання база до послейдней версии.

Есть либа https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate, тут все понятно, можно выкатывать структуру базы.

А если нужно какойто alter table запускать?)

Юзаю go с minikube (k8s). Docker image собираю через github actions.

Планирую подкрутить teamcity для деплоя в minikube (локально). В k8s можно указывать пробы на готовность апликухи. Исходя из этого можно либо деплоить апликуху после миграции, либо указывать задачу.

**И вопросы:**

- Если указывать задачу при деплои в k8s, то куда ее ложить? Это отдельный скрипт? Или командная строка з параметрами в go приложении? А как тогда откатывать? В laravel все лежит с кодом.
- Есть какие-то "хорошие практити" по миграции бд в go?
- Возможно с точки зрения DevOps миграции лучше делать иначе?)

Answer (score 1):

Попробую https://flywaydb.org, так как есть поддержка множества баз.

Уже есть в докере https://hub.docker.com/r/flyway/flyway